# In Responsive Bartik, add collapsible menu toggle to wide screen?

Tags: navigation, theming

Does anyone know how to enable the *collapsible menu/menu toggle* functionality that is part of Responsive Bartik on small screens to large screens?
It doesn't seem to be done solely by media queries.